# How to catch the exception thrown from flink's readFile(path)?

Tags: apache-flink

I use flink to monitor new files in hdfs (file is gzip format), and process them.

```
env.readFile(filePath)
```

It can work when file is valid,

but if gzip file is invalid, flink job will be killed.

There is exception log:

```
java.io.IOException: Error opening the Input Split hdfs://mdw:8020/user/data/15_077_4.gz [0,-1]: Not in GZIP format
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.open(FileInputFormat.java:824) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat.open(DelimitedInputFormat.java:472) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat.open(DelimitedInputFormat.java:49) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileReaderOperator.loadSplit(ContinuousFileReaderOperator.java:381) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileReaderOperator.access$300(ContinuousFileReaderOperator.java:88) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileReaderOperator$ReaderState$2.prepareToProcessRecord(ContinuousFileReaderOperator.java:112) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileReaderOperator.processRecord(ContinuousFileReaderOperator.java:322) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileReaderOperator.lambda$new$0(ContinuousFileReaderOperator.java:225) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:47) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:78) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:301) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:183) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:569) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:534) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:721) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:546) ~[k.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.compression.GzipInflaterInputStreamFactory.create(GzipInflaterInputStreamFactory.java:43) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.compression.GzipInflaterInputStreamFactory.create(GzipInflaterInputStreamFactory.java:32) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.decorateInputStream(FileInputFormat.java:848) ~[k.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.open(FileInputFormat.java:820) ~[k.jar:?]
    ... 16 more
```

I want to skip the invalid file, rather than kill flink.

But I don't know how to catch exception, because the exception is thrown by flink's internal code.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had more specific needs, so we wound up writing a custom `FlatMapFunction` that was constructed with a list of directories to check, and would received a regular "tickler" event from a custom source. When it got this event (in its `flatMap()` method) it would check if there were new files (matching some criteria), and if so then it would open the file, read entries, and emit them via the `Collector`. So in this situation we've got complete control over error handling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and modification. It's a good idea, i will try.